# Form data doesn't save to file (through CGI in python)

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

I made a form in HTML that's supposed to save some data through my university's server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>TI 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_form.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="dummy" id="dummy"></iframe>

    <h1>TI 3 - form</h1>

    <div class="formSection">
        <form action="../../../cgi-bin/toCsv.py" target="dummy" method="POST" name="studentForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <h3>Name: (*required):</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>

            <h3>Surname: (*required):</h3>
            <input type="text" name="surname"/>

            <h3>E-mail address: (*required):</h3>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>

            <h3>University year: (*required):</h3>
            <select name="year" size="1">
                <option value="0">Choose:</option>
                <option value="1">I</option>
                <option value="2">II</option>
                <option value="3">III</option>
                <option value="4">IV</option>
                <option value="5">V</option>
            </select>

            <br>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="subBt" value="Submit" />
            </p>
        </form>

    </div>

    <hr>

</body>
</html>
```

from where I call the python script called toCsv.py, that collects the data and is supposed to save them in the CSV file called data.csv:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import csv

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print 

studForm = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = studForm.getvalue("name")
surname = studForm.getvalue("surname")
email = studForm.getvalue("email")
year = studForm.getvalue("year")

data = [name, surname, email, year]
print "data" 
print data

with open('../4/pd1/3/data.csv', 'a') as file:
    write = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    write.writerow(data)
```

It seems that it collects and parses data the way it should. I tried removing the dummy iframe to debug. I filled the form and got the correct result:
`data ['Robert', 'Friedrich', 'lux@torpe.da', '1']`.

The script saves the data correctly to data.csv, when I call it straight from the UNIX terminal: `./toCsv.py`. (the data is obiously empty, but the commas are saved).

However, when I submit the form, nothing seems to be saved. What's the problem?

The js script just validates the data and I think it has nothing to do with the issue. I'll post it anyway, just to be sure.

```
function validate(){
    let name = document.studentForm.name.value;
    let surname = document.studentForm.surname.value;
    let email = document.studentForm.email.value;
    let year = document.studentForm.year.value;

    let valid = 1;
    let errorMessage = "";

    if (name.length === 0){
        valid = 0;
        document.studentForm.name.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        errorMessage += "No name!\n"
    }

    if (surname.length === 0){
        valid = 0;
        document.studentForm.surname.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        errorMessage += "No surname!\n"
    }

    if (email.length === 0){
        valid = 0;
        document.studentForm.email.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        errorMessage += "No e-mail!\n"
    }
    else if ((email.indexOf("@")==-1) || (email.length < 3)){
        valid = 0;
        document.studentForm.email.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        errorMessage += "Wrong e-mail format!\n"
    }

    if(year === "0"){
        valid = 0;
        document.studentForm.year.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        errorMessage += "No year chosen!"
    }

    if(valid){
        document.studentForm.name.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(100,255,100)';
        document.studentForm.surname.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(100,255,100)';
        document.studentForm.email.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(100,255,100)';
        document.studentForm.year.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(100,255,100)';
        alert("Form sent.");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert(errorMessage);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe use `try/except` to catch error and save it in file (but in the same folder). Maybe it will explain problem.

Comment: when you run server then may not be `../../..` but only `/cgi-bin/toCsv.py`. Server may uses different pathes or it may allow for scripts only in main folder   `/cgi-bin`

Comment: @furas nope, that makes it even worse. It used to find ```toCsv.py``` but did not save to ```data.csv```. Now it can't even find ```toCsv.py```. How to use try/catch? I've never learnt python, just my teacher wants us to use it

Comment: use google to find any tutorial with `try/except` - you will get more info than here in comment.

Comment: @furas but what error am I supposed to catch? Nothing seems wrong, the program doesn't error out. Also changing path to absolute ```/~6domagalski/cgi-bin/toCsv.py``` leads to the same outcome as ```../../../cgi-bin/toCsv.py```.

Comment: many servers runs code as different user, with different privilages, in different folder and without access to screen/terminal to display errors - so you may have error but you can't see it. Using logging you can see error message in file.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out myself. It was such a stupid mistake - simple access issue. 
`data.csv` couldn't be written to from outside. What I needed to do was just one simple line: `chmod 757 data.csv`. It used to be 755, and that's why there was a problem.